# Variable name appears in prompt

Tags: macos, bash

I'm trying to automate my daily task of opening my editor and "cd-ing" into a project folder at the same time by typing 'project something'. So far so good. The code is working. But I got some unexpected behavior. The current directory label is showing `Lukas-mbp:~sub_directory(2603m|master) $`. What is this `sub_directory` doing there. It is the variable name I'm using, as the code below. But can anyone tell why my terminal is showing that instead of the actual directory?

```
function project() {
  for directory in ~/projects/*
  do
    for sub_directory in $directory/*
    do
      if [[ "$sub_directory" =~ $1 ]]; then
        cd "$sub_directory"
        sublime $sub_directory
        return
      fi
    done
  done
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `PS1`? Do you run `project` from the command line?

Comment: Why bother with the `do` loops?  Can't you just do `(cd ~/projects/*/$1; sublime $1)`?

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple **wildcard** instead of doing all that unecessary looping! I've not, however, completely understood your subdirectories tree, so I've came with two alternatives, use whichever is appropriated. Add the function to *~/.bashrc*.

**1 - If your subdirectories tree is like this (works exactly as in your example*):**

```
~/projects/subdir1/target1/
~/projects/subdir1/target2/
~/projects/subdir2/target3/
~/projects/subdir2/target4/
```

The function will be like this:

```
function project {
    cd ~/projects/*/"$1"
    sublime .
    # or sublime ./*
}
```

* Keep in mind that if you have two or more *target* with the same name, but on different *subdir*, it will only match the first one, as will your example.

**2 - If your subdirectories tree is like this (which seems more common to me):**

```
~/projects/target1/
~/projects/target2/
~/projects/target3/
~/projects/target4/
```

The function will be like this:

```
function project {
    cd ~/projects/"$1"
    sublime .
    # or sublime ./*
}
```